# How do you remove Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I have no idea what was deleted or uninstalled or even what system ran previously on the computer.  The computers are public computers for an office and no one know's how to use this system!  Most people can't figure it out and have never even heard of it (I have because I knew someone who ran it)!!  So how do I remove it?  Is there anyway to just do a virtual restore?  I'm hoping it was windows 7 on here previously cause don't most 7 systems have a built in windows installation disk iso?  Anyone know how or if this can be fixed??  No we don't have the re-installation disks (if we did I would know the system and not have a problem) HELP!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got confused with Ubuntu and Ubuntu One.  To remove Ubuntu one (this is from my old answer):

> If you only want to remove Ubuntu One, type these in the terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone\*
> ```
>
> Ubuntu One will be removed.  If you don't know what Ubuntu One is,
>   [read here](http://one.ubuntu.com).

To remove Ubuntu:

If the System on your computer is a Dual-Boot system, Read my answer
[somewhere else](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on/143482#143482) for steps to remove ubuntu.

If you only have Ubuntu on those computers and you didn't clone your disk drive with a program like [Clonezilla](http://www.clonezilla.org) to backup, then sorry, you will need an Windows installation
 disk.

If (too many If's) you don't really have a Windows Installation CD, then you will just have to try and use Ubuntu.  Many Windows users hate Ubuntu at first, but after days of using it they feel more comfortable about it and liked it more than Windows.

And Windows 7 Computers usually comes with a **Recovery Partition**, not an installation ISO, since the manufacturer have to pay Microsoft a Windows Licence fee for every computer they sell.

Comment: Correct command is: **sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone*** (the asterisk is necessary) Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8146023&postcount=2

Comment: Also nix the **remove**.

Comment: Even better is `sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone\*`. Then, it still works right even if there is a file in the current directory whose name starts with `ubuntuone` (as in this case, the shell will perform expansion of the argument before it's passed to `apt-get`).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One is ubuntu's cloud storage solution.

Sounds like you just want rid of the Ubuntu operating system. Unfortunately unless you have some kind of restore image of the previous system you can't just undo the install. Maybe the system is dual booted in that you may be able to boot into Windows by rebooting the system and choosing windows at the bootloader.

If not then you may need to reinstall Windows using the disks that would of came with your computer.  If you cannot find them then call Microsoft they will gladly sell you some new ones.

Or you can just learn to use Ubuntu it's way better than windows and there's plenty of help around if you need it.